# How to get Java classpath separator?

Tags: java, classpath

How to programmatically get Java classpath separator used in value of java `-cp`/`-classpath` option?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

System property `path.separator` contains classpath separator for current platform. It can be obtained by

```java
System.getProperty("path.separator");
```

From [`System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) documentation:

> path.separator    Path separator (":" on UNIX)

Values are `:` for Linux and Mac OS, `;` for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, you can rely on the constant [`File.pathSeparatorChar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#pathSeparatorChar) if you expect a `char` or [`File.pathSeparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator) if you expect a `String`.

I quote the Javadoc of `File.pathSeparatorChar`:

> The system-dependent path-separator character. This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system property path.separator. This character is used to separate filenames in a sequence of files given as a path list. On UNIX systems, this character is ':'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is ';'.